# Having lots of open connections vs repeatedly opening and closing them

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I'm investigating some performance issues in our product.  We have several threads (order of tens) that are each doing some form of polling every couple of seconds, and every time we do that we are opening a connection to the DB, querying, then disposing.

So I'm wondering, would it be more efficient for each thread to keep an open connection to the DB so we don't have to go through the overhead of opening a connection every 2 seconds?  Or is it better to stick with the textbook `using` blocks?

Comment: Are not DB connections themselves pooled ?
What I mean is if you standard Oracle, Sql Server or MySQL, you get a feature of connection pooling.
Rather than creating a new thread and disposing them, you could try to use thread from the thread pool, rather than creating each one every time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing to learn about is [Connection pooling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca.aspx). You're already using it, don't change your code.

The question becomes: how many connections to claim in my config file?
And that's easy to change and measure.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, connection pooling *should* take care of it but if you are beating on the database with messaging or something like that to check on the status of things every few seconds then you could be filling up the database pool very quickly.  If you are on SQL Server, do an SP_WHO2 on the database in a query window and you'll see a lot of information: number of spids (connections open), blocking, etc.

Answer (score 0):

In general, connection setup and teardown is expensive; doing this multiple times in tens of threads might be crippling; note however that the solution you use might already be pooling connections for you (even if you're not aware of it), so this may not be necessary (see your manuals and configuration).

On the other hand, if you decide to implement some sort of connection pooling by yourself, check that your DB server could handle tens of extra connections (it probably should).